# ns-2.35 Mannasim installation

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have installed ns-2.35 (it's working).
I wanted to install Mannasim following this [Guide](http://www.nsnam.com/2013/06/mannasima-sensor-network-simulator-for.html)

However after the "make" command I get an error:

```
mannasim/leach/mac/leach-wireless-phy.o: In function `hdr_rca::offset()':
leach-wireless-phy.cc:(.text._ZN7hdr_rca6offsetEv[_ZN7hdr_rca6offsetEv]+0x5): 
undefined reference to `hdr_rca::offset_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ns] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command

```
make clean
```

followed by

```
make
```

has done it properly this time.

Answer (score 0):

---

Mannasim INFO http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/mannasim-ns235/ and http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/mannasim/

NS-2.35 build example, post #24 here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/ns-2-problem-lltype-812414/page2.html#post4970177

---